# If $f : [0,1] \to H$ is weakly continuous, is it bounded with respect to the norm of $H$ on $[0,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $f: [0,1] \to H$ be a mapping that is weakly continuous in the sense that
\begin{equation}
t \to \langle f(t), v \rangle_H
\end{equation}
is continuous in the ordinary sense for all $v \in H$.

Then, by the fact that any weakly convergent sequence is norm-bounded, I suspect that $\lVert f(t) \rVert$ is bounded for all $t \in [0,1]$.

However, since I have to deal with the continuum $[0,1]$, I do not see how to justify my guess, using the uniform boundedness principle.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: This is a typical, easy, application of Uniform Boundeness Principle.

Comment: Oh I just figured out...Yes, it is easier than I thought...

Comment: Since you know the result for sequences: If $f$ were unbounded it were unbounded on some sequence $t_n$ which has a convergent subsequence.